# Get an attribute in a template from a ManyToMany relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my Django 1.5 project I have a many-to-many relationship between two models:

```
class File(models.Model):
    #..
    subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length = 30, primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

What I want to do is, knowing the file, access to the subject in my HTML templates.

Of course `{{ file.subject }}` doesn't work.  I know that `{{ file.subject.subject }}` it's a query set that can be looped but, even if I try, I don't know how I can grab the right `Subject` object.

Is there a way to do it only from templates? Or it's best to pass it from the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be 0 or more subjects; if you just want to loop, do so with a `for` block over `file.subject.all()`:

```html
{% for subject in file.subject.all %}
    {{ subject.subject }}
{% empty %}
    Sorry, no subjects found.
{% endfor %}
```

If you need to find a specific subject, you'll have to query for it. Do so in the view; logic like this should be left to Python code:

```
subject = file.subject.filter(subject__startswith='Foo').first()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `join` template tag:

```
{{ file.subject.all|join:", " }}
```

or loop:

```
{% for subj in file.subject.all %}
     {{ subj }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```